# Gatling feeder - Feeder seems to be skipping users in CSV

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I recorded a script to log into a website and navigate it.  While it logs into users from the feeder, 1) it tends to log into one user more than others, and 2) it seems like it skips over users in the CSV.

In addition, it appears it finishes the simulation before the users get to complete the script.

How can I ensure all my users I specify in my setUp complete the script?

```
setUp(
    please.inject(
    nothingFor(4 seconds),
    atOnceUsers(10),
    nothingFor(2 seconds),
    rampUsers(200) over (25 seconds),
    nothingFor(2 seconds),
    rampUsers(400) over (30 seconds),
    nothingFor(5 seconds),
    rampUsers(1500) over (150 seconds),
).protocols(httpProtocol).throttle(
    reachRps(1300) in (120 seconds),
    holdFor(1 minute),
    jumpToRps(700),
    holdFor(2 hours)
)

)
```

As far as `rampUsers` is concerned, does that only inject virtual users?

Also, this is how I used the feeder.

```
val TestUsersCSV = csv("TestUsers.csv").circular
val please = scenario("FinalRecord").feed(TestUsersCSV).exec(login, chain_0)
```

One thing I've considered is putting a `.forever()` at the scenario level and then `.MaxDuration` in the setUp.  That will ensure my script will keep looping, right?

But why would my script be skipping users in the CSV?

Comment: Are you calling `feed(TestUsersCSV)` anywhere else then in `val please = ...`?

Comment: No. I'm only calling it at that scenario.

Comment: Well I never had a problem with feeder skipping records, it definitely is not a normal behavior and I doubt it is related to any configuration. Are there any errors / failing requests in your simulation? I think it requires some debugging. Setting proper logging (with LogBack) should help. Also your setting is very unusual, I'am wondering if you are not over-complicating it.